# Текст выходит за границу блока в описании новой привилегии

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, дизайн

Как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Задан был, но решения не имеет. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin , Почему не имеет? К примеру поставьте **width: 75%;** посмотрите что будет?